# Responding to a poor question

Tags: proverbs

There's a proverb in my native language (Norwegian) which is used as a reply to a person who complains about a *poor answer* given to his/her *poor question*. It says that the quality of the answer is relative to the quality of the question.

> - You asked me a poor question, so I'll respond with a poor answer.
>
> Roughly translated:
>
> - As asked, so answered

Is there a similar proverb in the English language?

Comment: Perhaps [tit for tat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tit_for_tat). It isn't used specifically for a _poor question/poor answer_ situation, but more or less covers what you're looking for.

Comment: I disagree with _tit for tat_; it has overtones of retaliation for a malicious deed, which doesn't fit the context of a poor question, since most such aren't deliberately so.

Comment: There is no such thing as a stupid question, only stupid people.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The literal, direct translation is the English idiom: "***ask a stupid question, get a stupid answer***".

Or, as we say in computer science: *garbage in, garbage out*.

Comment: As I'm a programmer for a living, +1 for `GIGO`.

Comment: As a programmer, you may have read "Godel, Escher, Bach", in which Hofstadter supplies the *perfect* response to a poorly-formed question: *Mu* ("I unask that question").  In my undergrad CS days, this wasn't an uncommon thing to say when someone asked a question which was unintelligible or embedded false premises. In fact, it got so popular among geeks, Mu made it into the design of Perl6 as the "null" object, which a function can return when passed nonsense or inapplicable arguments. WP writeup here: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Mu_%28negative%29#.22Unasking.22_the_question

Comment: GIGO should be first and in bold. It's literally the rough translation.

Answer (score 3):

'The pot calling the kettle black' is a more general proverb of this type. In this context it would imply 'who are you to say my answer is poor, when you've just asked such a poor question?'

My father always says 'a stupid question deserves a stupid answer', but this probably isn't what you're looking for!

Answer (score 2):

An idiom that does not apply literally,
but may come close to the spirit of your phrase, is ***you get what you pay for***. 
[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/you_get_what_you_pay_for) says that this is

> Primarily used to denigrate inexpensive goods as naturally inferior

and lists [***you pays your money and you takes your choice***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/you_pays_your_money_and_you_takes_your_choice) under the **See also** heading, although this is grammatically incorrect and of dubious relevance.

Answer (score 1):

***Tit For Tat***

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tit_for_tat) formally defines "tit for tat" as *an English saying meaning "equivalent retaliation"*.

> It is also a highly effective strategy in game theory for the iterated
>   prisoner's dilemma. The strategy was first introduced by Anatol
>   Rapoport in Robert Axelrod's two tournaments, held around 1980.
>   Notably, it was (on both occasions) both the simplest strategy and the
>   most successful in direct competition.
>
> An agent using this strategy will first cooperate, then subsequently
>   replicate an opponent's previous action. If the opponent previously
>   was cooperative, the agent is cooperative. If not, the agent is not.
>   This is similar to *superrationality and reciprocal altruism* in
>   biology.

Therefore, following the last paragraph quoted above, "***tit for tat***" can be, broadly speaking, applicable to the situation you describe in your question-

> ...used as a reply to a person who complaints about a poor answer
>   given to his/hers poor question. It says that the quality of the
>   answer is in relation to the quality of the question.

[The FreeDictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tit+for+tat) provides several definitions of this phrase-

- ***Repayment in kind, as for an injury; retaliation***.
- ***an equivalent given in return or retaliation; blow for blow***
- *Probably borrowed from Dutch tip for tap, "blow for blow."*

I would say all of them seem to fit in well with the situation you have in mind.

Comment: If you want to swank with Latin, the phrase is ***quid pro quo***, lit 'which for which' or 'something for something'.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah! Here is a beautiful one for these situations...

In two parts, it goes...

**Do not answer a fool according to his folly, Or you will also be like him.**

**Answer a fool according to his folly, lest he be wise in his own eyes.**

(The Bible, Proverbs 26:4-5)

Comment: Good answer, Roby. BTW- I edited your answer to include the reference.  What version did you quote?

Comment: Hi, and thank you the first verse is NASB and the second is ESV. http://biblehub.com/proverbs/26-4.htm http://biblehub.com/proverbs/26-5.htm